# Android canvas does not draw LinearGradient

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I am trying to draw path with some LinearGradient shader, but it is drawn as transparent, this is my simplified example:

```
    private val _shader = LinearGradient(
        50f,0f,
        50f,100f,
        0xff0000,0x00ff00,
        Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
    )
    private val _paint by lazy {
        Paint().apply {
            shader = _shader
        }
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0f,0f,100f,100f ,_paint)
    }
```

I tried changing layerType and hardwareAccelerated but it doesn't help.

Comment: Apparently my colors were not defined properly as hex, "Color.RED" works fine

Comment: Yeah, change your color values to include an explicit alpha value – e.g., `0xffff0000` – otherwise it's zero, transparent.